# how to get the response from the user in whatsapp api

Tags: python, python-3.x, whatsapp

I'm new to Whatsapp Api and currently i want to know how can i get the response from the user using the request or other tools in python. What i manage to achieve is to send messages but i don't know how to get the reply that user sent. if you can guide me in this problem, it would be great. I cant use third party to do this integration like twilio and others

below is code used for sending message

```py
import json
import requests

token=""
phone=""
version="v15.0"
sender_phone=""
message="something"
url = f'https://graph.facebook.com/{version}/{phone}/messages'
header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'}

data = {
            "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
            "to": sender_phone,
            "type": "text",
            "text":{
                "body": message
            }
            }
data = json.dumps(data)
response = requests.post(url=url,headers=header, data=data)
print(response.text)
```

Thank you

Comment: You can get the message notifications in [webhook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/guides/set-up-webhooks).

Comment: @turivishal Thanks for your reply, how can i use webhooks that you mentioned in python to be connected with my application.

Comment: It is a big process you need to read the documentation. my question is how were you able to find that send message code? if you did that from meta [whatsapp business API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/get-started) then there is a whole process described step by step, just follow the documentation.

Comment: @turivishal i dont know much about webhook in general so i will research about it. Then if i faced issue in the integration of webhook with python then i will post in stackoverflow. Thank you

Comment: @new_dev for the webook, you need to expose an open api from your system, which when WhatsApp sends data to it, you can process the data, store it maybe in a database , send a reply message to the customer etc.